# Multiple sites/realms in FreeIPA

Tags: freeipa

To start off, my experience lies in networking (Cisco) and Windows.  That being said, I have been set off on a project to design a multi-site FreeIPA installation.  I have single site FreeIPA without a problem.  Where I am running into problems is multi-site.

Let's say that I have three sites:

- site1.example.com
- site2.example.com
- site3.example.com

I want to have as my overarching realm example.com.  Do I need to have an IPA server to run example.com?

When I created the first IPA server, ipa.site1.example.com, and used the example.com realm name, no dns zone was created for example.com.  I only have a dns zone for site1.example.com.

The documentation for realms and dns zones seems to be next to nonexistent (or I am just looking in the wrong direction).  If anyone has experience with this set up, or can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Your realm should be a subdomain of your existing Internet domain name, not the name itself.

Comment: This topic is discussed regularly. Please look at this thread on freeipa-users@ mailing list: https://www.redhat.com/archives/freeipa-users/2016-December/msg00220.html as one of recent examples.

Answer (score 3):

No you don't need an IPA-Server running in "example.com" but you need a correctly set-up DNS Server that correctly delegates the subdomains "site1/2/3.exmaple.com" to their authoritative DNS (I'd suggest let the IPA-servers handle their DNS themselves).

For each realm just add the following two records to your "example.com" Zone - and you're done. I'd suggest you point the A-Records directly to your "subdomain" IPA-Server and have them handle their own SubDomains DNS-Zone.

```
 ipa01.site1.example.com.     A        10.20.30.40
 site1.example.com            NS       ipa01.site1.example.com.
```

I just did that as well - with two realms "test.example.com" and prod.example.com without an existing "example.com".

But be aware that the `ipa-install-server` script by default might use real public ROOT-DNS-Servers to resolve your domain even if the system itself has other resolvers configured so you have to define the forwarders on the ipa-server-install command-line that know how to handle e.g. like.

```
ipa-server-install --hostname=ipa01.test.example.com \
  --domain=test.example.com                          \
  --ds-password=secret                               \
  --admin-password=moresecret                        \
  --setup-dns -r TEST.EXAMPLE.COM                    \
  --forwarder=XX.XX.XX.XX                            \
  --forward-policy=only
```

where XX.XX.XX.XX is the IP of your DNS-Server for "example.com"

This should do the trick.  Have a look at `man ipa-server-install` and search for "forward" to get more details.